# Is There An "Erase Lines Mode" In Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to 'erase lines' in Illustrator similar to the way it's done in Adobe Flash?

The clearest example is around 06:40 of this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr2Y3DKHiJg

Basically in Flash you have eraser mode that you can change to just erase parts of the stroke of an object. Is that possible in Illustrator? I want to essentially do what the guy does in that video. Put two objects on top of each other and then erase the stroke to create the impression of one shape. I have faked it with clipping masks, etc. but I thought this could be an easier solution if it's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Illustrator has an eraser tool.

A better method is to use the Appearance Panel though.

Group the two objects, apply a stroke via the Appearance Panel, then move the stroke below "Contents".

[image: Appearance stroke]

Answer (score 0):

Scissors Tool (C)
Mark the first and last point on shape's stroke,
to make a partial selection, then delete it by pressing "del",