# Adobe Illustrator Share shape edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, cc-2014

I am relatively new to Adobe Illustrator, so I am not very familiar with the tools.
[image: Screenshot]

I have two paths, with stroke inside selected for the stroke method. I would like to have the two shapes share an edge (the thick one), so the thick edge will be normal thickness rather than twice as thick.

The picture in [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13476/removing-part-of-a-stroke-and-adding-a-gradient-to-a-stroke-in-illustrator-cs5) has a picture which shows two shapes sharing an edge, but with different fills. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The first sentence of the post you linked states, "The top and bottom half are two separate objects each with their own gradient."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First draw your shape as one object. Then grab the pen tool again and draw a center line from the left end point to the right end point.

[image: main object]

Select both the shape and the path in the middle and go to the stroke options. Make sure the stroke is center align. I picked 4 pt black stroke for my example.

[image: Center align stroke]

What that looks like

[image: Center align stroke]

I then went to expand appearance. I then selected all and used the pathfinder options and clicked on divide.

[image: stroke width]

Delete the ends with the direct select tool. Also use direct select tool to change color of bottom shape.

Result

[image: end result]