# How to non-destructively generate filled foreground and background shapes from a single shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

For example, I have a basic shape with a fill and stroke (or other kind of appearance effects applied to get this result):

[image]

From this, I want two separate shapes, each a simple filled shape with no stroke. One shape is the extracted fill part, and the other is a fill of the outline shape essentially:

[image] [image]

Once I have these shapes I would like to further modify the center shape by subtracting other shapes from it, while retaining the original background shape. For example to end up with these two shapes:

[image] [image]

The key constraint here is that I do not want to re-create the base shape in several different places to generate these two shapes. The base shape may change frequently, and it would take too much time to replace it in multiple places each time.

I can almost accomplish this by using two fills, one with offset path, but I don't know how to apply effects like pathfinder to one of the fills to merge it with other shapes.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! It's hard for me to tell if what you want is possible without knowing exactly why you need it. I don't think you will ever be able to dynamically apply separate effects to the outer black shape - only to the gray base shape. Could it be a solution to keep your gray base shapes grouped and add the black outer shape as an effect/stroke to that group?

Comment: One could simply apply a [stroke to grouped base objects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13476/removing-part-of-a-stroke-and-adding-a-gradient-to-a-stroke-in-illustrator-cs5)....  Without more detail on *why* you need to use pathfinder on only a portion of objects, and retain some sort of separate outline object would be needed for certainty. (The stroke could be expanded and merged when done editing objects. See the link.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added some more info. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your key constraint correctly – that you are using the same shape in multiple places – then perhaps turning the shape into a symbol could be a solution. Then you can simply edit the symbol and all of the instances will update accordingly.  Plus you could create similar shapes as separate symbols and replace the original if needed.

Comment: I still don't get it.. copy the original shapes. Place the copies on a layer below. Edit the originals all you want. You *aren't* going to be able to dynamically alter base shapes and *not* alter anything "connected" to those shapes (via effects or other operations).

Comment: Basically, it's like I want to pass one shape to two separate functions that would each generate a shape. One function would apply the subtract with additional shapes, the other would simply apply offset path. This type of workflow is possible in other applications, and I was curious if there's anything like it in illustrator. The appearance panel comes very close to offering what I want, but it lacks the ability to use pathfinder with shapes generated by fill effects.

Comment: Yeah I don't think anything like that is available in Illustrator. You can replicate a shape via a number of dynamic methods, but if the original shape changes, so does the replicated shape. And 77 **can't** run pathfinder operations on a defined original shape without also altering any dynamically replicated iterations.

Comment: I suspect it's far more of a workflow issue than anything, but without a detailed, step-by-step procedural breakdown it's hard to provide any alternatives.