# How to stroke only part of the path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to add a outline, so I select the object and apply a stroke. But I want be able to stroke only the outer path not the internal (marked yellow). [image]Is this even possible? tried using scissors and it makes the shape go haywire. Newbie here.

Comment: Can you simply move that shape behind the others? If you are looking to merely have a single outline for that entire collection of objects, see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13476/removing-part-of-a-stroke-and-adding-a-gradient-to-a-stroke-in-illustrator-cs5?rq=1

Comment: Yeah but I dont wish to make any changes to the size or shape... 
P.S: o I see u edited your answer and added a link.. that kinda gives me a direction thanks, ill try.

Comment: Changing the stacking order of shapes doesn't alter the shapes in any way. The *only* way to have a stroke around part of filled object is to draw a separate stroke. It *can't be done* with a stroke on the same filled shape.

Comment: Thanks@scott, I tried to follow the instructions, but I am unable to drag the stroke below the stack for some reason.

Comment: got it to work.. thanks.. the key was to first select all the objects, make them a group and in the appearance tab add the stroke. and then I was able to reorder the stack.

Comment: So.. did that link solve this question? If it did I'll close this as a duplicate