# Trying to create a stroke like the effect in PS but in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hoping to get some Adobe Illustrator advice here.

I narrate through the video but I am basically trying to make a stroke (used as a PS term) on a group of objects but have the resulting stroke be it's own object.

Any help is much appreciated.

Screen recording: https://photos.app.goo.gl/LZKepFDhwGZ9aJa6A

Comment: If you are seeking to add a stroke around *all **grouped** items* then this may help: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/is-there-an-erase-lines-mode-in-illustrator

Answer (score 1):

It's also called a *stroke* in Illustrator. (This is a basic feature of Illustrator so you could probably benefit from viewing some basic tutorials to get started.)

Select the object which has a *fill* and click the *Swap fill and stroke* button. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Now the fill turns transparent and the stroke gets a color instead. Click the *Stroke* button to be able to select a color for the stroke. (You can of course also have both a stroke and a fill on one object.)

In the *Stroke* panel you can adjust the *Weight*. In your specific case, make sure to set *Align Stroke* to *Align Stroke to Outside*.

[image]

The stroke will keep being dynamic in the sense that you can adjust the settings in *Stroke* panel later. If you want the stroke to be *expanded* into a closed shape which instead has a fill it can be done using *Object > Expand Appearance*. It can have advantages in some situations, but you won't be able to edit the settings anymore.